# Unrecognized Arguments Error in TensorFlow generate_tfrecord.py Script

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection, tfrecord

I am facing an issue while trying to use the generate_tfrecord.py script in TensorFlow to create TFRecord files for my object detection dataset. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
usage: generate_tfrecord.py [-h] [-x XML_DIR] [-l LABELS_PATH] [-o OUTPUT_PATH] [-i IMAGE_DIR]
                            [-c CSV_PATH]
generate_tfrecord.py: error: unrecognized arguments: data/train
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: `python {files['TF_RECORD_SCRIPT']} -x {os.path.join('gdrive', 'MyDrive','car data', 'test')} -l {files['LABELMAP']} -o {os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'test.record')'
```

Here is the command I am using:

```
!python {files['TF_RECORD_SCRIPT']} -x {os.path.join('gdrive', 'MyDrive','car data', 'train')} -l {files['LABELMAP']} -o {os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'train.record')}
!python {files['TF_RECORD_SCRIPT']} -x {os.path.join('gdrive', 'MyDrive','car data', 'test')} -l {files['LABELMAP']} -o {os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'test.record')
```

The dataset is stored in Google Drive, and I am using Google Colab.
I have already mounted Google Drive in Colab, and the paths seem to be correct.
The script is expected to convert XML annotations to TFRecord format.

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

If any additional information is needed to provide a more accurate assessment, please feel free to inquire.

I've been trying to use the generate_tfrecord.py script in TensorFlow to cook up some TFRecord files for my object detection dataset.

I double-checked my paths for the XML annotations and images – Google Drive is happily in the mix. I used the -x, -l, -i, -o options, thinking they'd do the trick.

Even made sure TensorFlow and  (cuDNN, cuFFT, cuBLAS) are up to date.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.tecmint.com/bash-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token/) help?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing  indicates that the script generate_tfrecord.py is being used with unrecognized arguments. This error is likely due to incorrect command

```
usage: generate_tfrecord.py [-h] [-x XML_DIR] [-l LABELS_PATH] [-o OUTPUT_PATH] [-i IMAGE_DIR]
                            [-c CSV_PATH] generate_tfrecord.py: error: unrecognized arguments: data/train /bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `(' /bin/bash: -c: line 1: `python {files['TF_RECORD_SCRIPT']} -x {os.path.join('gdrive', 'MyDrive','car data', 'test')} -l {files['LABELMAP']} -o {os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'test.record')'
```

You Commnad:-

```
!python {files['TF_RECORD_SCRIPT']} -x {os.path.join('gdrive', 'MyDrive','car data', 'train')} -l {files['LABELMAP']} -o {os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'train.record')}
```

It appears you're attempting to incorporate Python f-strings into a shell command, which is not supported as f-strings are specific to Python syntax and cannot be used directly within shell commands.

To fix this, you need to ensure that the command is constructed correctly for the shell to interpret. Here's a corrected version using Python string formatting instead of f-strings:

Try this :-

```
!python {files['TF_RECORD_SCRIPT']} -x "gdrive/MyDrive/car data/train" -l {files['LABELMAP']} -o {os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'train.record')}
```

In this corrected version, the paths are specified as strings directly, and os.path.join() is not used because the command is being executed in a shell context, not in Python.